# how to deal with error 490?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my access datebase i have a list of clients, each have a first name, last name, id and so on...
In addition, each client has a folder (read only folder) I pre-opened for him, with files about him in it. I created a button to open that specific folder, but it keeps giving me:

> runtime error 490: cannot open the specified file

The VB code:

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()
    Dim strInput As String
    strInput = Forms![frmCostumer]![lName]
    Application.FollowHyperlink "D:\SkyDrive\klienti\strInput"
End Sub
```

The form name is `frmCostumer`, and the folder is named by the last name of the client (named `lName`).

Comment: Your comment "have no idea how to use VB, I just copied it from another forum" is more than enough for me to draw two conclusions: you are asking in the wrong place (minimum knowledge to ask, etc.); and your request seems a bit pointless anyway: why you ask how to deal with something in something (VB.NET) you cannot deal with?... The best way to deal with this error seems to write a proper code, what apparently you cannot deliver.

Comment: PS: VB.NET and VBA are different things. Also VB (without .NET) is assumed to be Visual Basic before .NET (VB6 or older), which is also different than both VB.NET and VBA.

Comment: The point is that I know it should work but it doesn't, and i'm asking for your help.. @varocarbas
I don't need a lot of VB, just to fix this problem. everything else is basic ms-access...

Comment: If you know that it should work why you write the "I have no idea..." bit? Also Application.FollowHyperlink seems VBA and thus you should remove the VB.NET tag and stop refering to VB (which can easily be confused with VB.NET or VB6) and just focus on VBA. In any case this error is pretty descriptive and the source of your problem might be the given file (or its properties, current state...); perhaps you should clarify all these issues to get help quickly.

Comment: @varocarbas thanks for the edit!
This isn't even a file, just a regular folder..

Comment: If I don't know that (you can have files with no extension; I do this a lot for temporary storage when I have to rely on such a not-so-good option), how is Access-VBA expected to know it? (or any helper)? Do you expect people (and computers) to magically understand what you mean/want/aim, don't you? It sounds a good way to either get errors or not be helped here. I can only come up with a way to increase your chances of get quick help: write "urgent" in the title of this question ;)

Comment: @varocarbas apperantly, the folder is a 'read only' folder, and for some reason i can't change that.. Do you think that can be the reason for the error?

Comment: Better wait for someone with more experience on vba-access. It depends upon what you are doing with the folder. Read-only elements can be read without any problem; if you are intending to access it with other permission (to write/delete a file in it, for example), then yes. The whole point of my advise (other than ridiculising an, IMHO, ridiculous behaviour, at least, here) was suggesting you to add all the relevant information. Example of irrelevant (or better: negative) info: "have no idea how to use VB"; example of relevant info: "my folder is read-only and I get a cannot-open-file error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `Application.FollowHyperlink` a constant `"string literal"` specifying a folder that apparently does not exist. Try this instead:

```vbs
Application.FollowHyperlink "D:\SkyDrive\klienti\" & strInput
```